# Regular expression to detect table names in oracle code

Tags: python, regex, re-python

I would like to detect which tables are used to get data from in procedure and function code in oracle.

```
... from <tablename>;
... from <tablename> <alias>;
... from <tablename> <alias> where ...;
... from <tablename> <alias> (, <tablename> <alias>)* where ...
... from <tablename> <alias> (<join> <tablename> <alias> on <onclause>)* where ...
```

These are some of the possible constructions.

I would like to use the module 're' in python. Any insights of how can i achieve this?

This is what I came up with so far:

`[(procedure.split()[0], re.findall('FROM \w+ \w* [WHERE|,|;]*', procedure, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) for procedure in procedures]`

Comment: You need to show us clearer input and output samples.

Comment: You may possibly want to try this before: https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse

Comment: Not sure, but probably `re.findall(r'(?i)FROM ([^(),\s]+(?:[,\s]+[^,()\s]+)*)', s)` will do this work for you.

Comment: I think you are going to find this very hard to do in a regular expression. Consider writing a proper SQL parser, using, say, `pyparsing`. An example for SQL that you might find a useful starting point here: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleSQL.py